# Temporary connectivity failure on iPad

Tags: ipad, network, data-synchronization

We have an iPad, two iPhones, and a MacBook Pro.

Three of them run [apps](https://AnkiSRS.net) that synchronize data with each other via a webserver dedicated to that app (not a general purpose cloud).

Occasionally, this app on the iPad will timeout trying to sync.  When this happens, Apple’s App Store also fails to connect, but websites still work normally.

Also when this is happening, neither the iPhones nor the MacBook Pro (MBP) have any problems, not even with that app (Anki).  Rebooting the iPad, rebooting the router, and switching the iPad from the router to the iPhone hotspot does not fix it.  It fixes itself after an hour or more.

UPDATE: Fourteen months later, with more than one update to IOS and to Anki, the problem still exists.  But I discovered another detail: it happens consistently when the iPad is plugged into the 2019 MBP which is closed (asleep).  Haven't tried it open.
But if I unplug the cable, and try again, it works.

UPDATE TWO: Happens whether the MBP is open or closed.  Did `netstat -rn` with and without the sync cable.  Difference was numerous instances of "bridge100" when I though internet sharing was off.  Turns out at some time, Apple introduced "Content Caching" to "speed up internet access."  It default to on, and it turns on Internet sharing.  I turned both off, but that did ***not*** resolve the issue.

Also, in response to the comment, I looked at the iPad’s settings with and without the cable.  Cable does not change any of them.  All the settings are manual.  Oddly, it has **two** IPv6 addresses, when I did not give it any myself.  But the rest are as I specified.  Router is an Airport Extreme without disk.  DNS is 1.1.1.1 and 8.8.8.8 (external).

What might this be?

Comment: Are you running the latest version of Ankiweb 2.1.33 (Released 2020-08-30, build 3f403040.)?  The change logs reference several bug fixes for sync issues.  https://changes.ankiweb.net/#/. Search the page for "sync". There's also a fix for iOS/iPadOS for network timeouts. Otherwise it may be a network proxy, DNS issue, etc.

Comment: Yes, I am.  But the version of Anki can't explain the App Store also failing at the same time when Safari and e-mail keep working.  And Anki never having the problem on the iPhone.

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of the network settings on the iPad when it is not connected to the MacBook Pro, and one where it is? (including IP addresses)